# Swift: Array of base class does not call subclass function implementation

Tags: ios, swift, unit-testing, mocking

I'm trying to inject a fake instance into a unit test for a class depending on SimplePing, a NSObject subclass. My class has a property `var simplePings: [SimplePing]` which in my unit test I set as an array of FakeSimplePing. However, when the class goes in the array and calls `simplePing.start()`, it calls the SimplePing.start implementation instead of FakeSimplePing's, even though when I debug I see that the instance type is FakeSimplePing.

When the property is just a single SimplePing, the unit test uses the FakeSimplePing.start and the test passes. Does this have something to do with Swift and arrays of superclasses?

```
class Pinger : NSObject {
   private var simplePings: [SimplePing] = []

   func pingLocation(location: Location) -> Signal<Double, NoError> {
       let simplePings = location.serverIPs.map { (serverIP: String) -> SimplePing in
           let simplePing = SimplePing(hostName: serverIP)
           simplePing?.delegate = self
           return simplePing
    }
       configureDependencies(simplePings)
       simplePings.forEach { $0.start() }

       return signal
   }

   func configureDependencies(simplePings: [SimplePing]) {
       if self.simplePings.isEmpty {
           self.simplePings = simplePings
       }
   }
}



class FakeSimplePing: SimplePing {
    var receivedStart = false
    var receivedSendPingWithData = false
    var fakeHostName: String!
    override var hostName: String {
        return fakeHostName
    }

    convenience init(hostName: String) {
        self.init()
        fakeHostName = hostName
    }

    override func start() {
        // This does not get called
        receivedStart = true
        delegate?.simplePing?(self, didStartWithAddress: nil)
        delegate?.simplePing?(self, didReceivePingResponsePacket: nil)
    }

    override func sendPingWithData(data: NSData!) {
        receivedSendPingWithData = true
    }
}
```

And the failing test:

```
            beforeEach {
                fakeSimplePing = FakeSimplePing(hostName: serverIP)
                fakeSimplePing.delegate = pinger
                pinger.configureDependencies([fakeSimplePing])
            }

            it("pings server with data") {
                pinger.pingLocation(location)

                expect(fakeSimplePing.receivedSendPingWithData).toEventually(beTrue())
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem (I believe...) is in the naming in `pingLocation`

in the line

```
let simplePings = location.serverIPs.map { ....
```

you use the same name as of your property

```
private var simplePings: [SimplePing] = []
```

so you may think you're defining a new variable with the `let`, but actually, you may just use your property and change it on the way, so it got changed to `SimplePing` array, as it returns from the map

try to change your method into:

```
func pingLocation(location: Location) -> Signal<Double, NoError> {
       let tempSimplePings = location.serverIPs.map { (serverIP: String) -> SimplePing in
           let simplePing = SimplePing(hostName: serverIP)
           simplePing?.delegate = self
           return simplePing
    }
       configureDependencies(tempSimplePings)
       simplePings.forEach { $0.start() }

       return signal
   }
```

Comment: Wow thank you so much, can't believe I missed that. The specific problem was the `simplePings.forEach` line, which was using the array created by the map, instead of using the property that was set by the configureDependencies function. I changed it to `self.simplePings.forEach` instead. Good catch!

Comment: Nice! So my answer wasn't correct after all :) because I thought, from some stupid reason, it could change the property. But anyway, I think that it's not a good practice to name your variables as your properties, I advice you to change the name of the variable instead, so you could use your properties freely (without 'self'), and not to worry of these kind of bugs.. Any way, I'm glad I could help :)